# Refresh a part of webpage with content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a webpage as a client, and I am looking for a program to refresh just a part of the page not the whole page. This part consist of a calendar.
I have tried the code below:

```
('#caldiv').fadeOut('slow').load('/Global-Appointment/Scripts/fullcalendar.js.php').fadeIn('slow'); (1000);
('#caldiv').fadeOut('slow').load('/Global-Appointment/Scripts/fullcalendar.js.php').fadeIn('slow'); (1000);
```

The script above refresh the calendar table only every 1 seconde without bringing contents.

I would like to refresh a calendar with data (content) in a real time.

Comment: Why the `/` before `Global-Appointment`? And also, `(1000);` is an expression that doesnt do anything.

Comment: Use `setInterval`

Answer (score 0):

You can go pure JS to achieve that:

```
<html>
    <div id="where-data-will-be-shown"></div>
</html>

[...]

<script>
    setInterval(async () => { // Create an interval
        const data = JSON.parse(await (await fetch("/where-data-comes-from")).text());
        document.getElementById("where-data-will-be-shown").innerHTML = data;
    }, 1000)
</script>
```

Or you could use a framework. You can use a simple and straighforward one like [vue.js](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/04/30/vue-fetch-http-get-request-examples), or a more complex one like [react](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) that gives you more flexibility.

Comment: Hello, I tried the script you send but did not work, the page remains constant with no refresh, probably there is a mistake somewhere. Considering the framework I have never work with it.